# MacBook Pro 5th Generation with two external 30'' Monitors (DELL)

Tags: macbook, dvi

I think this is currently IMPOSSIBLE, unless you want to use a USB-to-DVI adapter which provides low resolution.

Currently you can only have ONE 30-inch monitor with the apple adapter at 2560x1600.

Any hope for this?

Has anyone tried using the apple adapter with another usb-to-dvi adapter?

Comment: How about this: http://www.engadget.com/2008/03/19/gefens-usb-to-dvi-adapter-handles-uxga/

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no hope for this. If you want dual displays, you need dual DVI outputs. End of story.

Comment: No, you need four. 30" is dual link

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Graphics eXpansion Module](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/solutions/mac/) from Matrox which lets you combine two physical displays into one. The downside is, your Mac will recognize the two displays as one large display, so window maximization and the menu bar will work a bit differently on that display.